# История слов, придуманных поэтами

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

Определите, какой путь в своем употреблении прошли слова: созвездие, маятник, рудник (введены М. В. Ломоносовым), солдат, бездарь.

Историю развития значений последних двух слов удалось найти, но историю слов, придуманных Ломоносовым, к сожалению, найти не удалось.

Может, у кого-нибудь есть информация об этих словах?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70448/discussion-on-question-by-----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Слово «созвездие» (от лат. constellatio) означает «коллекция (или группа) звезд». До середины XVII века синонимом термина созвездие было слово "астеризм" (от греч. aster - звезда).Ломоносов оставил один термин - созвездие, иностранное "изъял" из обращения.

   Раньше созвездиями называли плоскую часть небесной сферы, по которой размещены яркие  звезды, составляющие какую-нибудь фигуру, сейчас под созвездиями ученые  понимают определённую область, один из 88 участков звёздного неба, конус, в который входит все, что внутри него. Туда входят все светила, находящиеся на определенном участке, даже самые-самые тусклые и далёкие. Это помогает ученым точно ориентироваться в звёздном пространстве.

2.Маятник - это так называемый радиэстезический эффект, известный человечеству со времен VIII века до н.э. Термин «радиэстезия», в переводе на русский, означает «ощущение волн, колебаний».
[http://enc-dic.com/semenov/Majatnik-1149/маятник](http://enc-dic.com/semenov/Majatnik-1149/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)
Слово «маятник» как «ритмично качающийся стержень, прикрепленный верхней частью к неподвижной точке», а также «колесо, регулирующее ход часов», используется в русском языке с XVII в. История употребления слова связана опять-таки с Ломоносовым. В то время по-научному маятник назывался “перпендикулы”,а Ломоносов оставил только слово маятник с др.-русским значением "качаться","махать", возможно, от "маяться".(по другой версии это была калька с французского «balancier» -маятник).

История развития теории маятника - https://how-to-ll.com/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0
 Энциклопедия Брокгауза и Ефрона

3.Рудник как горнодобывающее предприятие, расположенное на территории рудного месторождения и осуществляющее в основном подземную добычу полезного ископаемого в России назывался немецким термином  “бергверк”, Ломоносов рекомендовал говорить по-русски -  рудник.

В старину рудником называли рудокопа, горного рабочего.

4.Солдат - первоначально так называли воинов-наемников, появившихся в ХV веке в Италии. В России в обиход слово введено во времена первого Романова, Михаила Федоровича, который учредил солдатские полки по европейскому образцу. Потом солдатами стали называть всех простых военнослужащих в отличие от офицеров.

5.Бе́здарь - от прил. бездарный. Слово образовано поэтом Игорем Северяниным, использовано в его стихотворении «Прощальная поэза (Ответ Валерию Брюсову на его послание)», 1912, входящем в сборник «Громокипящий кубок», 1913: «Вокруг — талантливые трусы/ И обнаглевшая бездарь… /И только Вы, Валерий Брюсов,/ Как некий равный государь…».

Безда́рь была у Игоря Северянина женского рода и относилась к собирательным существительным. Сейчас оно стало обозначать представителей мужского пола и используется для устной характеристики личностных качеств человека. Слово остается в разговорной лексике, в словарях есть помета "устаревшее".

Comment: Людмила, скажите, пожалуйста, а есть ли источники (ссылки, данные вами, не работают), которые подтверждают информацию, описанную в пп. 1–3?

Comment: http://www.litmir.me/br/?b=143935&p=105  https://www.vslovar.org.ru/phys/125.html
http://5fan.ru/wievjob.php?id=3001

Comment: авторитетное издание...

Comment: А в чём именно Вы сомневаетесь? Откройте любую биографию Ломоносова, везде есть о терминах, которые он ввёл. О созвездиях - в учебниках астрономии.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, замечу, что слово *солдат* не было «придумано» никаким поэтом и встречается в текстах по крайней мере XVII века:

> Древнейшее значение здесь было: наемник, состоящий на жалованье. Слово связано с итальянским «со́льдо» — название монеты и «жалованье». Человек, получающий «со́льдо», назывался «coльда́тo». К нам слово прибыло через немецкий язык, где оно превратилось в «зoльда́т».
>
> *(Л. В. Успенский)*

Во-вторых, слово *созвездие*, по всей видимости, является в конечном счете калькой позднелатинского *constellationem* (nom. *constellatio*) 'полный звезд (сущ.)'. Ввел его Ломоносов (https://www.msu.ru/lomonosov/science/in.html; [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

В-третьих, слово *маятник* не было «придумано» Ломоносовым, вопреки статье на сайте МГУ (см. выше): оно встречается уже в текстах XVII века («Переписная книга домовой казны патриарха Никона» 1658 года). Очевидно, книжное образование от *маять(ся)*. Возможно, калька с фр. *balancier*. (См. словарь Черных.) Было ли оно введено Ломоносовым — вопрос, достоверных источников не нашел.

В-четвертых, слово *рудник* также навряд ли «придумано» Ломоносовым ввиду наличия славянских параллелей со значением 'рудокоп': польское, в-луж. *rudnik*... К сожалению, у меня сейчас нет доступа к текстам, поэтому найти пример с использованием этого слова до рождения Ломоносова не могу. Однако они наверняка есть.

Слова очень редко «придумываются» кем-либо, это скорее исключения.

P. S. Все слова (за исключением *рудника*) имели более или менее то же значение, что и сейчас.

Comment: Но он мог придумать эти слова на основе уже существующих корней. Слова "солдат" и "бездарь" придумал не Ломоносов, об этом и никто не говорил. Вопрос-то в другом: какой путь они прошли в своем употреблении, т. е. важна их история после появления на свет.

Comment: @Серж не мог: два из них были «придуманы» до его рождения. (Я про «солдата» и Ломоносова ничего не говорил, обратите внимание, пожалуйста.) Их значение практически не поменялось. Разве что «рудник» мог изначально значить «тот, кто копает», но это надо проверять. «Маятник» и сейчас маятник (см. Черных), равно как и «созвездие» (значение «группа выдающихся деятелей» которого очевидным путем связано с метафорой, имеющей место в лексико-семантическом варианте слова «звезда» „популярный, известный человек“).